# PHP mailer with encoding problem in ISO-2022-JP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a email function need to send a email to both client and customer, and I have to encode both subject and body to specific character encoding which is "ISO-2022-JP".
And here's my problem:

```
$subject = "=?iso-2022-jp?B?".base64_encode(mb_convert_encoding($subject,"JIS","UTF-8"))."?=";
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
//服务器配置
$mail->CharSet ="ISO-2022-JP";   
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; 
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;    
$mail->Subject = $subject;
```

When I check my mail box and the email title which I've received was:

```
=?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCJVshPCVgJVohPCU4JCskaSROJCpMZCQkOWckbyQ7GyhC?=
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer does this for you. Set the character set like this:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'iso-2022-jp';
```

Then you can use native ISO-2022-JP text everywhere, and you don't need to do any conversions or encoding - though bear in mind that means that all your scripts, database and everything else needs to use that same character set too. You may find it's easier (and safer) to use UTF-8 instead, since it's universal.